# Force horizontal table scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table within a modal popup. I want the table to expand beyond its container if necessary and give a horizontal scrollbar. Currently, it just doubles the height of the row if it needs to: [image]

I want the horizontal behaviour to be the same as the vertical behaviour (expand and provide scrollbar). This is the PHP / HTML generating the table:

```
<div class="row"><div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>History:</label>
    <div id="table-scroll">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <th>Date</th><th>From User</th><th>To User</th>
            <th>From Location</th><th>To Location</th><th>By</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($history as $h){ ;?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$h['date'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$h['from_user'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$h['to_user'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$h['from_location'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$h['to_location'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$h['by_user'];?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ;?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

This is the current CSS applied:

```
#table-scroll {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#table-scroll th {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: give overflow-x:scroll to #table-scroll

Comment: @VishalPanara doesn't work - the table rows still grow in height to accomodate their contents.

Comment: It is happening because It's a responsive table, If you don't want to make this happen then remove this "table table-bordered table-condensed" classes and make your custom table.

Comment: @vishal-panara - this is not a responsive table - the table-bordered class adds a border and the table-condensed class removes half of the normally applied padding from the table. In order to be a responsive table - the entire table needs to be wrapped in a a table-responsive div, which allows Bootstrap css to be applied - such as the overflow and horizontal scroll,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `white-space:nowrap` to force it to get the text in one line only and then overflow data will come in scroll.

```
#table-scroll {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#table-scroll table{
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:100%;
}
#table-scroll th {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the table function as you want it - you need to wrap it in a table-responsive tag - this will force a horizontal scrollbar to appear on the tablet sized viewport -check out the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

```
<div class='table-responsive'>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <th>Date</th><th>From User</th><th>To User</th>
            <th>From Location</th><th>To Location</th><th>By</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($history as $h){ ;?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?=$h['date'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$h['from_user'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$h['to_user'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$h['from_location'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$h['to_location'];?></td>
                    <td><?=$h['by_user'];?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ;?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

I would also suggest that you rethink your design - any design that calls for a large amount of content (tabular or otherwise) to be displayed in a modal is asking the modal to do more than it really should. But thats just my opinion.